# Subtracting columns with the same prefix based on different suffix loop ends with starts with

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I have a large dataset that is organized as follows

```
Date.       A_H.   B_H.   C_H.   D_H.   A_L.   B_L.   C_L.   D_L
1/1/18.      4.    6.       7.      6.   3.     2     2.     4
1/2/18       5.    7.       3.      5.   6.     3     1.     4
```

I want to add columns that are the High - the Low for each respective letter. So I want, in this example, 4 more columns, one for each letter that subtracts the respective L from the H. However my true data frame has about 150 pairs so I want a non manual way of making the prefix match and subtracting based on suffix.

I have tried many approaches including a for loop with mutate, mapping, and a method using sub select and reduce. a is my data frame

```
Aa <- names(a) %>%
    sub(“_\\d+$”, “”, .) %>%
    unique 
Aa %>% 
    map(~a %>%
        select(matches(.x))%>%
        reduce(‘-‘)) %>%
        set_names(paste0(“HL_”, Aa)) %>%
    bind_cols(a, .)
```

But I get the error “matches is an unused argument”

I also try

```
Aa <- map(c(“A”, “B”, “C”, “D”), ~a %>%
                      mutate(!!as.name(paste0(.x, “_HL”)) := !!as.name(paste0(.x, “_H”)) - !!as.name(paste0(.x, “_L”)))) %>%
    reduce(left_join)
```

But i get the error !as.name(paste0(.x, “_L”)) : invalid argument type

I also try 
      Aa <- c(“A”, “B”, “C”, “D”)

```
 for(i in 1:length(Aa)){
     Aaa <- a %>% mutate(a, !!as.name(paste0(Aa[i], “_HL”)) := !!as.name(paste0(Aa[i], “_H”)) - !!as.name(paste0(Aa[i], “_L”)))}
```

But with that I get the “LHS must be a name or string error”

Any advice on what I am trying to do? 
   Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you edit and post the `dput` of the example data as it is not clear whether the `.` at the end of column names is present in all columns or just a print issue

Comment: I cannot because I can’t post it directly.

Comment: I didn't get your comment.  I would use `dput(head(a, 2))`

Comment: What is `.x`? You use it several times but don't post an example of it. Please use `dput` to post a [mcve] of all the relevant data

Comment: I cannot access stackoverflow on the computer I am using so I am posting on here from my phone. Sorry

Comment: .x is not in my data. It was included in example code that I found online trying to solve similar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
bind_cols(df %>%
 gather(var, val, -matches("(_L)|(Date)")) %>%
 select(Date., var, val),
 df %>%
 gather(var, val, -matches("(_H)|(Date)")) %>%
 select(Date., var, val)) %>%
 mutate(res1 = paste0(var, "_", var1), 
        res2 = val-val1) %>%
 select(Date., res1, res2) %>%
 spread(res1, res2) %>%
 left_join(df, by = c("Date." = "Date."))

    Date. A_H._A_L. B_H._B_L. C_H._C_L. D_H._D_L. A_H. B_H. C_H. D_H. A_L. B_L. C_L. D_L.
1 1/1/18.         1         4         5         2    4    6    7    6    3    2    2    4
2  1/2/18        -1         4         2         1    5    7    3    5    6    3    1    4
```

It, first, separately, transforms the `_H` and `_L`columns from wide to long format. In the second step, it combines the two by columns. After this step, it creates the names of the new variables by combining the names of the `_H` and `_L` columns and subtracts the `_L` columns from `_H` columns. Finally, it transforms the new variables with the desired results to the original wide format and then joins it with the original df based on "Date.".

Or:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -Date.) %>%
 mutate(temp = gsub("_.*$", "", var)) %>%
 arrange(Date., temp) %>%
 group_by(temp = gl(length(var)/2, 2)) %>%
 mutate(res1 = paste(var, collapse = "_"),
        res2 = val - lead(val)) %>%
 na.omit() %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(Date., res1, res2) %>%
 spread(res1, res2) %>%
 left_join(df, by = c("Date." = "Date."))
```

In this case, it, first, transforms the data from wide to long format, excluding the "Date." column. Second, it takes the characters before `_` from the variable names and arranges the data according "Date." and this. Third, for every two rows, it assigns a factor level and groups by it. Forth, it combines together the names of the variables and does the subtraction. Finally, it returns the data to the original wide format and joins it with the original df.

Or with base R you can try something like:

```
res <- df[, grepl("_H", colnames(df))] - df[, grepl("_L", colnames(df))]

colnames(res) <- paste(colnames(df[, grepl("_H", colnames(df))]),
                       colnames(df[, grepl("_L", colnames(df))]), sep = "_")

cbind(df, res)

    Date. A_H. B_H. C_H. D_H. A_L. B_L. C_L. D_L A_H._A_L. B_H._B_L. C_H._C_L. D_H._D_L
1 1/1/18.    4    6    7    6    3    2    2   4         1         4         5        2
2  1/2/18    5    7    3    5    6    3    1   4        -1         4         2        1
```

Here it, first, identifies the columns that contains `_H` and `_L`. Second, it subtracts the `_L` columns from `_H` columns. Third, it combines the column names of `_H` and `_L` columns and assigns it to the results as column names. Finally, it combines the results with the old df.